# Does django + mod_wsgi require threaded programming discipline?

Tags: python, django, thread-safety, mod-wsgi

We're rolling out our first django application under mod_wsgi as

```
`WSGIDaemonProcess our-appname processes=6 threads=15'`
```

and we're having a discussion about whether our Python code and the Redis and Postgres libraries it uses needs to be thread-safe or not.

From what I can tell from reading the mod_wsgi documentation, even though the apache worker is processing requests with multiple **apache** threads, our **python** code is for all intents and purposes single-threaded.  I don't see any warnings on the mod_wsgi docs saying "Beware!! You now have to worry about Global Data and Thread Safety!"  but there's also no explicit "Don't Worry About Threads There Aren't Any".

We're not doing anything explicitly with threads in our python code, there is no mention of them in anything we've written.

But some people here are of the opinion that since we're running with `threads=15` that we are now in in the multi-threaded world.

Can anyone clarify what's actually going on here?  Is our Python code now subject to multiple threads of execution through the same data where it wasn't before, or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes obviously you are running multi-threaded app and it will create problems if you don't take care with globals, Class attributes etc

If you need to keep something globally, keep it in  thread local storage.

Here is a quote from [modwsgi doc, Building_A_Portable_Application](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading#Building_A_Portable_Application)

> 3 . An application must be re-entrant, or simply put, be able to be called concurrently by multiple threads at the same time. Data which
>   needs to exist for the life of the request, would need to be stored as
>   stack based data, thread local data, or cached in the WSGI application
>   environment. Global variables within the actual application module
>   cannot be used for this purpose.

So I think you have been sufficiently warned.

Answer (score 1):

The python interpreter is not thread-safe, particularly because of reference counting, so threads cannot access python objects concurrently in the same process space.  There is no way you can configure mod_wsgi to get around this, accidentally or intentionally, because the interpreter is protected by the GIL (global interpreter lock).  Therefore, you don't have to worry about the particularly tricky thread-safety issues that come with the risk of simultaneous threads accessing the same memory objects (memory locking etc).

Some webservers such as gunicorn with a gevent backer will have multiple threads in memory concurrently so that no individual process needs to be blocked on I/O (database access, network access, etc).  This may also be the case with mod_wsgi.  However, this is implemented in such a way that you shouldn't need to worry about it in your application code -- if your application is safe to use in multiprocessing it should also be safe to use in this sort of limited non-concurrent threading model.

Of course, you can't use global variables or dynamically edit parts of your application as it runs, but if you are doing anything like that in Django then you will encounter problems even before you have to worry about threading.  Django and other web frameworks are designed so that data is passed in as a request and out as a response without having to worry about thread/process safety within that model.

You DO need to worry about concurrent access to data stores (esp. database entries), as for any web application.  Code defensively when it comes to database access.

Comment: Sorry, but I find your leading in phrase very confusing. The Python interpreter itself is thread safe, if it wasn't then it would be crashing all over the place. The internal state of the Python interpreter and management of the reference counts is mediated by the GIL as you say and is what ensures that it is safe to use the Python interpreter with multiple threads. So bad way of explaining it. Also gunicorn with gevent doesn't have multiple threads. When using gevent they are technically coroutines not threads albeit it makes them look like threads.

Comment: Now the issue of application level code being thread safe is a different issue, but don't confuse that with whether the Python interpreter is thread safe.

Comment: On the first count, I suppose that's true, though I'm not sure it's any less accurate to describe the python interpreter as not thread safe for memory operations on python objects at the same time than it is to explain that it is thread safe because the GIL prevents threads from doing the above.  On the second count, I agree; gevent uses "green threads" which are technically not threads -- I should have explained that.

Comment: Unfortunately people have a habit of grabbing hold of phrases such as 'python interpreter is not thread-safe' and without understanding the context take away that and little else. We don't want to have people thinking that Python isn't anything but a wonderful language to use. So just thought it was worth clarifying.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm having trouble reconciling the other comment on this thread, which says:

"An application must be re-entrant"

with your comment where you say:

"Django and other web frameworks are designed so that data is passed in as a request and out as a response without having to worry about thread/process safety within that model."

It seems that those two statements contradict each other.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: WSGI applications must be re-entrant, but *Django and Python take care of that for you* in almost all cases.  As long as you accept a request, process it, and send back a response without doing anything extremely unusual, you don't have to think about thread safety at all.

So, the documentation that states that WSGI applications must be thread safe is technically accurate, but I'm saying that's something that is important to the framework (Django) but not to the application programmer in most cases. You would have to try hard to violate thread safety in a Django app.

Comment: I understood your question as "does this setting on mod_wsgi affect how I should be thinking about coding my Django app" and the answer is "no".  Your Django app, if it is coded such that it will run properly at all, will almost certainly run with threading enabled in mod_wsgi with no modifications.  All of those issues are taken care of by the framework and the Python interpreter.

Comment: _You would have to try hard to violate thread safety in a Django app._ I think this is not true, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think Andrew's answer is a little bit misleading. The fact that CPython (note that there are other Python implementations such as Jython and PyPy) has the GIL does not mean you don't have to worry about your code being thread safe! Because of the GIL, no two threads in one process can be active at the same time. But parallelism is simulated by periodically switching between threads. And such a context switch can happen **anytime** during the execution of your program. As an example, if you have a module `foo` containing a "global" variable `x`, then the following method might output anything from 2, 3, 4, ..., depending on the number of threads executing that same method:

```
def bar():
    foo.x = 1
    # a context switch might happen here!
    foo.x = foo.x + 1
    # or here!
    print(foo.x)
```

Actually, you can configure mod_wsgi to use max. 1 thread. And then you don't have to worry about thread safety. But the correctness of your program would depend on the configuration of the web server, which is a very undesirable situation.